# PHP Mailer doesn't run

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have two sites (different domains and registras) that I'm trying to use PHP Mailer for.  One site works perfectly but the other returns the ever helpful white page as soon as it calls

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;
```

I have copied the code from one site to the other, amending file paths etc. and I have instered echo's so I can see the correct files being accessed, it just won't run.

I'm not sure what information is needed to help in finding an answer - please can anyone help?

Comment: So you know your `require_once('PHPMailerAutoload.php')` statement is working? Is there anything in your PHP error_log?

Comment: The only reason for that happening is that you've not loaded the class beforehand, or that your autoloader is not set up correctly (if you're using composer, which you should be). Look in your server's error log. There is not enough info here to write a proper answer.

Comment: Your new site may not support the correct php version or php extensions that are required by php Mailer. Try to enable error reporting in your php application and post the error message.